# PHP Return Values from JSON Objects

Tags: php, json

```
array(85) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#9 (18) {
    ["offer_id"]=>
    string(8) "12345678"
    ["offer_name"]=>
    string(39) "Offer Name"
    ["offer_desc"]=>
    string(209) "Offer Description"
    ["call_to_action"]=>
    string(57) "Offer CTA"
    ["offer_url"]=>
    string(80) "Offer URL"
    ["offer_url_easy"]=>
    string(106) "Offer URL Easy"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#11 (17) {
    ["offer_id"]=>
    string(8) "87654321"
    ["offer_name"]=>
    string(24) "Offer Name 2"
    ["offer_desc"]=>
    string(107) "Offer Description 2"
    ["call_to_action"]=>
    string(107) "Offer CTA 2"
    ["offer_url"]=>
    string(80) "Offer URL 2"
    ["offer_url_easy"]=>
    string(106) "Offer URL Easy 2"
  }
```

I am pulling a response from an API which contains an array with objects inside. I am trying to go through each object and get the value of each key.

For example I want to output:
Offer ID: 12345678,
Offer ID 2: 87654321

Currently my code is only outputting one ID (the first objects ID).

```
$arr = $offer_data->response->offers; //Outputs above array

foreach ($arr as $value) 
{
    return $value->offer_id;
}
```

Output: 12345678

Note: This is inside a function that I just echo.

Been trying different ways for hours, finally coming here. Thanks for any help you provide.

Comment: Are you sure the JSON data is being interpreted as an associative array? If not it may just be a case of accessing the data like so; 
`$value["offer_id"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are returning at first iteration.

```
function test()
{
  $arr = $offer_data->response->offers; //Outputs above array

  $result = [];
  foreach ($arr as $value) {
     $result[] = $value->offer_id;
  }

  return $result;
}

$ids = test();

print_r($ids);
```

Comment: That's it! As I posted the question I found that doing the foreach outside of the function it would return as expected but inside, not. That's the answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

As of PHP 7(when it started to support objects as input) you can use array_column to extract all the values in one go...

```
return array_column($offer_data->response->offers, "offer_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
$arr[] = $offer_data->response->offers;
```